# Ionic 4 Origin ionic://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ionic-framework, cors, ionic4

In my Ionic 4 Angular project I get the following error when requesting a json file from a server in my iOS simulator.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myServer.com/api due to access control checks.
>   cordova.js:1540
>
> Failed to load resource: Origin ionic://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

In the Chrome Browser with Access-Controls-origin plugin I do not get the error. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: please specify with server-side technology your using

Answer (score -1):

Follow this link - [3 Ways to Fix the CORS Error — and How the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header Works](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9). The first option (install the moesif CORS extension)  worked for me.

CORS errors are common in web apps when a cross-origin request is made but the server doesn't return the required headers in the response (is not CORS-enabled). It only happens when you're running the app from your localhost for testing purposes.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*') header at the requested resource.

Comment: Please explain your answer with some brief comment like why exactly do we need to do so.

Comment: Because that's the way HTTPRequests works under CORS. The Server holding the response has to accept incoming requests from the domain sending the request. To do so you have to configure your server response setting a matching Allow-Origin header